# Problems with unexpectedly short solutions

Tags: inequality, big-list

Problems with unexpectedly short solutions

This was inspired by
the following problem on quora:

Given that real non-zero numbers 
$a, b, c, d$ 
satisfy 
$^2+11^2+21^2+27^2
\le 6(+2+3)
$, How would you prove that 
$a, b, c, d$
are consecutive terms
of a geometric progression?

I hadn't seem this
type of problem before,
but after a while,
I came up with this solution:

If
$f(a, b, c, d)
=^2+11^2+21^2+27^2
- 6(+2+3)
$
then
$ f(a, b, c, d)= (a-3b)^2+2(3c-b)^2+3(3d-c)^2
$.
Therefore,
if $f(a, b, c, d) \le 0$
then
$a=3b, b=3c, c=3d
$
so
$a=27d, b=9d, c=3d$.

In case you want to generalize this,
the $6$ on the right comes from
$6 = 2\cdot 3$,
and the $1, 2, 3$ on the right
comes from the coefficients
of the squared terms.

Anyway,
the brevity of this solution 
struck me,
and I got to wondering
what other problems
had unexpectedly short solutions.

So that's my question:
what other problems
have unexpectedly short solutions.

I'll start things off
with this one:

Show that
$n^{1/n} \to 1$
as integral $n \to \infty$.

Answer:

By Bernoulli's inequality,
$(1+\frac1{\sqrt{n}})^n
\ge 1+\frac{n}{\sqrt{n}}
\gt \sqrt{n}
$.
Raising to the $2/n$ power,
$n^{1/n}
\lt (1+\frac1{\sqrt{n}})^2
\lt 1+\frac{3}{\sqrt{n}}
\to 1
$.

Your turn.